# Is it legal to track the installations of a free plugin

Tags: joomla, tracking

By this question I like to ask how legal is to track the installation of a free Joomla Module.

I already have create some Joomla Modules, and I like to track the amount of installations.

The only purpose of the trackink will be to track the web sites that using that module, nothing more, nothing less.

But I am wondering, is that legal ?

Comment: I suspect this has more to do with "ethicalicity" than "legality". But, in any case, SO is *not* a legal advice site so .. OT.

Comment: The one downvoted my question can explain what's wrong in my question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really the place to be asking this type of question.

Instead of tracking amount of installations, why not track the amount of downloads from your website? Would be much easier and ethical. Could be done with a simple bit of PHP or JS.

Comment: The plugin is downloaded from joomla repository, so I cannot track the downloads from there

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't ask for legal advice from a programmers community. Best advice is to ask a laywer.

But if I were to guess, NOT allowed without the explicit user permission.